# Non-adiabatic evolution and time-dependent adiabatic parameter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, time-evolution, adiabatic, lattice-model

I am dealing with the dynamics of a two-bands lattice system. The idea is that you have a lattice model of free fermions, with some hopping amplitudes and on-site energies.The lattice have two fermion species per site, and therefore the model has two energy bands. In this problem, each band is the negative of the other (i.e. you have self-energies $\pm E_k$, with $k$ the quasi-momentum).

I want to understand the following problem: you prepare the system at the half-filling groundstate (i.e. all the modes with negative energies are occupied, and the rest are unoccupied). Then, some of the parameters become time-dependent in a non-adiabatic way (for example, they grow exponentially for a certain period of time). This implies that the adiabatic theorem is not fulfilled, and therefore the system is no longer in the groundstate, but in an excited state with a certain spectrum of excitations.

To check whether the adiabatic theorem is fulfilled or not, one has to check if the following condition holds
$$
\langle v_k^+(\eta)|\dot{v}_k^-(\eta)\rangle\ll E_k(t)\Rightarrow\frac{1}{E_k(t)}\langle v_k^+(\eta)|\dot{v}_k^-(\eta)\rangle\equiv\xi_k(t)\ll 1.
$$

Here, $\{|v_k^\pm(t)\rangle\}$ are the eigenvectors of the system, $\hat{H}(t)|v_k^\pm(t)\rangle=\pm E_k(t)|v_k^\pm(t)\rangle$ (I assume momentum-conservation due to translational invariance), and I introduce the **adiabatic coefficient** $\xi_k(t)$. The dot represents derivatives with respect to time. My question is related to the fact that this coefficient is generally time dependent. Therefore, if the Hamiltonian evolves non-adiabatically in a continuous way for a certain amount of time, this coefficient will have a varying behavior. I would like to know what mode is the most excited one, but since the parameter that controls this is time dependent, for each time there is a different $k$-dependence. I thought of two different ways:

- Idea 1: Calculate the time-average of this paramater, and find the maximum of this new time-independent parameter as a function of $k$,

$$\Xi_k=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T\xi_k(t)dt,
$$ where $T$ is the total duration of the time-dependence of the parameters.

- Idea 2: Think of $\xi_k(t)$ as a two-dimensional surface, i.e. as a function of time and $k$ (discrete in the $k$ direction). Then, find the maximum of that surface. This will give a maximum time and a maximum $k$. This $k$ will be the most excited mode.

However, I have little intuition about this point, and these are just some sketch ideas that I am not sure to have any precise meaning.

Comment: Where did you get your "adiabatic condition" (your first equation)? It doesn't make much sense to me. Note also that since $v^\pm$ are eigenvectors related to different eigenvalues their scalar product is zero.

Comment: True! It was a typo. It is the scalar product between one normalized vector and the time derivative of the other. I have already corrected it. To my knowledge, this is the conventional condition that one uses to study adiabaticity.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. In any case, what is that you are trying to achieve ultimately? Are you trying to assess how much non-adiabatic your evolution is?

Comment: Exactly, I would like to understand if the value of this parameter allows one to obtain predictions about the non-adiabaticity of the process. For example: does $\xi_{k_1}>\xi_{k_2}$ imply that the mode $k_1$ will get more excited than $k_2$? What happens if this inequality is time-dependent? More generally: is this parameter giving some precise, quantitative information about the dynamical process beyond adiabaticity, or is it just meaningful when it is small, as to ensure that the adiabatic approximation holds?

Comment: If you have access to numerics and you want to assess how much 'adiabatic' you are, the best thing is to plot the population of the ground state (or the level you started from in general). Coming to your question the answer is no: *this parameter does not give precise, quantitative information about the dynamical process beyond adiabaticity*.

Comment: Yes, I have some numerical results. I solved the equations of motion and calculated the expectation values of the population in each Bloch state (for each band). However, I wondered if i could get some analytical results by means of this adiabatic parameter. Thank you for clarifying that it is not a timeworthy path to follow! :-)

Comment: PS I assume that momentum is conserved in your process so you only consider excitations from the lowest to the upper band (by the way the gap is then $2E_k$) and not intra-band excitations.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Momentum is conserved. I meant that maybe there was some way to analytically predict that if $\xi_{k_1}>\xi_{k_2}$, then $\langle\hat{c}^\dagger_{\uparrow,\,k_1}\hat{c}_{\uparrow,\,k_1}\rangle>\langle\hat{c}^\dagger_{\uparrow,\,k_2}\hat{c}_{\uparrow,\,k_2}\rangle$, where $\hat{c}^\dagger_{\uparrow,\,k}$ creates a fermion in the upper band with momentum $k$.

Comment: Your system seem to have only 2 levels per $k$ so there's not much that can happen. So it's possible that your conjecture holds most of the time. In the general case that would definitely not be the case. Note that some two level system with certain time dependence can be solved exactly (one is the Landau-Zener model).

Comment: PS if you write your precise model I may be able to say more.